# Should I get a 18/25 tube or a 25/32 tube?

Tags: innertube

I have a 25mm size tyre and I'm ordering some inner tubes on the net.

So far, I seem to have a choice between either the 18/25 range or the 25/32 range.

Both would fit but would one size be better than another?

Would the 25/32 tube heavier to accommodate the 32mm tyres and would the 18/25 size tube would be easier to puncture because it's at the maximum stretch?

Or would this be largely negligible?

Comment: @JamesBradbury - ok yep, that other question answers my question perfectly. Happy for this one to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

The difference in weight is practically non-existent, and puncture resistance is a property of the tire.

You may be able to pack an 18/25 in your spare parts kit a little easier than the 25/32, but that still isn't much of a big difference.

Just get whichever is cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to prefer smaller tube sizes when I have this choice because there is less material to bunch up when installing and it's less likely to get pinched between the tire bead and the rim during installation.

The disadvantage can be when patching.  Smaller tubes need to stretch more to fill the space, and patches may not stretch as much or as evenly depending on the type of patch you use. It's rarely a deal breaker, but you need to just be careful when fitting the patch on.